Does MODIS dataset (MOD09GQ) require atmospheric correction to calculate NDVI?
It took a dataset of satellite images with a high frequency of reception (1 day) to work. The work consists in studying the change in the NDVI coefficient at a certain site during the year.
I took pictures from 2008-2023 from here. There are 2 channels - red and near infrared. They also have a 16-bit quality matrix attached to them.
The original reference to the dataset indicates that all images are preprocessed (atmospheric correction, etc.), however, when analyzing individual pixels, according to the values of the bits, no correction is performed:
QUALITY VALUES FOR THE AREA 1: [4096, 7425, 7683, 2723, 3811, 4305, 7633, 2451]:

2451 - the zenith of the sun >=86 degrees (ERROR), without correction
2723 - the zenith of the sun is 85-86 degrees (ERROR), without correction
3811 - L1B data error on 2 channels, without correction
4096 - highest quality, without correction
4305 - correction of channel 2 was carried out with an error, without correction
7425 - correction of channel 1 was carried out with an error, without correction
7633 - correction of both channels was carried out with an error, without correction
7683 - error of L1B data on the 1st channel, without correction


Do I need to make a correction and, if so, what library is there for this in Python?

No, you are misunderstanding the QA bits.
You don't need to correct anything, all data that was of good enough quality to be corrected, has been corrected. Any data that wasn't corrected you should just exclude. You can also choose to exclude data that was corrected but the quality of one or both band was less than ideal.
MODIS QA Bits are read right to left (least significant) order. In python, you can use the bitwise right shift >> and bitwise and & operators to extract the bits you want to read.
E.g. using the values you provided "4096, 7425, 7683, 2723, 3811, 4305, 7633, 2451":
test_values = [4096, 7425, 7683, 2723, 3811, 4305, 7633, 2451]

modland_desc = {
    '00': "corrected product produced at ideal quality all bands",
    '01': "corrected product produced at less than ideal quality some or all bands",
    '10': "corrected product not produced due to cloud effects all bands",
    '11': "corrected product not produced due to other reasons some or all bands may be fill value"
}

quality_desc = {
    '0000': "highest quality" ,
    '0111': "noisy detector",
    '1000': "dead detector, data interpolated in L1B",
    '1001': "solar zenith >= 86 degrees",
    '1010': "solar zenith >= 85 and < 86 degrees",
    '1011': "missing input",
    '1100': "internal constant used in place of climatological data for at least one atmospheric constant",
    '1101': "correction out of bounds, pixel constrained to extreme allowable value",
    '1110': "L1B data faulty",
    '1111': "not processed due to deep ocean or clouds"
}

for val in test_values:

    modland_qa = (val & 3)  # extract bits 0-1
    band_1_quality = (val >> 4) & 15  # extract bits 4-7
    band_2_quality = (val >> 8) & 15  # extract bits 8-11

    corrected = modland_qa < 2
    band_1_quality_desc = quality_desc[format(band_1_quality, 'b').rjust(4 , '0')]
    band_2_quality_desc = quality_desc[format(band_2_quality, 'b').rjust(4 , '0')]

    print(f"Value = {val}")
    print(f"Corrected = {corrected} - {modland_desc[format(modland_qa, 'b').rjust(2 , '0')]}")
    print(f"Band 1 quality = {band_1_quality} = {band_1_quality_desc}")
    print(f"Band 2 quality = {band_2_quality} = {band_2_quality_desc}")
    print("-" * 20)

Output:
Value = 4096
Corrected = True - corrected product produced at ideal quality all bands
Band 1 quality = 0 = highest quality
Band 2 quality = 0 = highest quality
--------------------
Value = 7425
Corrected = True - corrected product produced at less than ideal quality some or all bands
Band 1 quality = 0 = highest quality
Band 2 quality = 13 = correction out of bounds, pixel constrained to extreme allowable value
--------------------
Value = 7683
Corrected = False - corrected product not produced due to other reasons some or all bands may be fill value
Band 1 quality = 0 = highest quality
Band 2 quality = 14 = L1B data faulty
--------------------
Value = 2723
Corrected = False - corrected product not produced due to other reasons some or all bands may be fill value
Band 1 quality = 10 = solar zenith >= 85 and < 86 degrees
Band 2 quality = 10 = solar zenith >= 85 and < 86 degrees
--------------------
Value = 3811
Corrected = False - corrected product not produced due to other reasons some or all bands may be fill value
Band 1 quality = 14 = L1B data faulty
Band 2 quality = 14 = L1B data faulty
--------------------
Value = 4305
Corrected = True - corrected product produced at less than ideal quality some or all bands
Band 1 quality = 13 = correction out of bounds, pixel constrained to extreme allowable value
Band 2 quality = 0 = highest quality
--------------------
Value = 7633
Corrected = True - corrected product produced at less than ideal quality some or all bands
Band 1 quality = 13 = correction out of bounds, pixel constrained to extreme allowable value
Band 2 quality = 13 = correction out of bounds, pixel constrained to extreme allowable value
--------------------
Value = 2451
Corrected = False - corrected product not produced due to other reasons some or all bands may be fill value
Band 1 quality = 9 = solar zenith >= 86 degrees
Band 2 quality = 9 = solar zenith >= 86 degrees
--------------------


A very interesting scheme, thanks
